Error when trying to open txt file in Python
I'm making an app using Custom Tkinter, and in this app I want to create buttons based on .txt files in a folder, and make the buttons copy the content of these .txt files. Simple copy / paste buttons.
This class for the buttons worked GREAT on my mac, but now on windows it gives me error.
I've checked multiple discussions with no luck. example tried "encoding="utf-8"", didn't work.
class CopyPaste(customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        global counter
        counter = 1

        self.Header = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Template Answers",
                                             font=("Arial", 20))
        self.Header.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        target_directory = "C:/ToolKit Files"

        def read_file(file_path):
            with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                content = file.read()
            return content

        def create_button(self, file_path):

            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

            def on_button_click():
                pyperclip.copy(read_file(file_path))

            button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text=file_name, command=on_button_click)
            button.grid(row=counter, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        def create_buttons(self, target_directory):

            file_names = [file for file in os.listdir(target_directory) if file.endswith('.txt')]
            for file_name in file_names:
                global counter
                file_path = os.path.join(target_directory, file_name)
                create_button(self, file_path)
                counter += 1

        create_buttons(self, target_directory)

After running this script I receive:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\SidekickToolKit\venv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\SidekickToolKit\main.py", line 162, in on_button_click
    pyperclip.copy(read_file(file_path))
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\SidekickToolKit\main.py", line 154, in read_file
    content = file.read()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 448: character maps to <undefined>

Help is greatly appreciated :D

On my end, it works just fine. I think one of the characters you entered in one of the .txt files cannot be readen by python. Try changing the encoder reading the files or try changing the content of the .txt files.

@fastattack
Hello!
Thank you, although I've tried changing the content of the files although Now it is still not copying the files, just a blank copy... :(
How do I change the encoder reading the files?
Thanks a lot!

your code looks fine, I think what is left to be done which triggers the error, UnicodeDecodeErrortraceback is for you to tell Python theencoding` to use to read the file.
Here is the update of your code:

def read_file(file_path):
       # wrap the entire code snippet in a try-catch block
       try:
           with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
               content = file.read()
           return content
      # catch the error if any
       except UnicodeDecodeError:
           return f'Error reading file {file}.'

I believe your code should work now since you have set the encoding to utf-8. If the encoding set to utf-8did not work after you must have updated your os, I use Linux though, then you can set this —errors='ignore' to where we put the encoding parameter. Goodluck mate.

Hi Thanks for that!
It works better now, but I also realized that it creates 2 buttons of each txt files.
the first set of buttons are named "._FileName.txt" and are giving the error, and the other set of buttons are named "FileName.txt" (The correct way and they are working)
Why might this be? It seems like the "Create buttons" loop is running twice with different results?

Hello @Kooritsmani, kindly mark the answer  as correct since it solved your initial problem, so that if someone having similar challange based on your title could easily follow the answer and resolve the problem him/she has. For this second question you asked, please create another issue or questions regarding it since it is not part of the original question, then I shall try my best, or any other pythonistas, can answer you. I wish you all the best.

Thank you so much! It is all working brilliantly now :)
Cheers!
@blaisemart
